# Angular Button Text Cuts Off After Adding a New Component

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm not very good at HTML. In my app, I defined 4 buttons. After that, I added a drop box. But adding that, made the texts of buttons cut off at the middle. Before, the buttons were fine. Here is my code, what should I add to make the buttons symmetrical again?

HTML:

```
 <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" class="m-8">
            <mat-form-field ppearance="outline" fxFlex class="pr-4">
                <mat-label>Yazıcı Adı</mat-label>
                <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedPrinter">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let prm of printerList" [value]="prm">
                        {{prm.Name}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
            <button mat-button matRipple class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12" (click)="save()"> Etiket Güncelle </button>
            <button mat-button matRipple class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12" (click)="printSticker()"> Etiket Yazdır </button>
            <!-- <button mat-button matRipple class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12" matTooltip="Linke Git" (click)="copyText(_stickerData?.StickerData);goToLink()"> <mat-icon>open_in_new</mat-icon> Ön İzleme </button> -->
            <button mat-button matRipple class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12" (click)="imageSource()"> Ön İzleme </button>
            <button mat-button matRipple class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12" (click)="close()"> Kapat </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the dropdown and the buttons from each other by using different `divs`.

Try this;

```
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="50" class="mt-8">
        <mat-form-field ppearance="outline" fxFlex class="pr-4">
            <mat-label>Yazıcı Adı</mat-label>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedPrinter">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let prm of printerList" [value]="prm">
                    {{prm.Name}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" class="wrap">
        <button mat-button matRipple class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12" (click)="save()"> Etiket Güncelle </button>
        <button mat-button matRipple class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12" (click)="printSticker()"> Etiket Yazdır </button>
        <!-- <button mat-button matRipple class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12" matTooltip="Linke Git" (click)="copyText(_stickerData?.StickerData);goToLink()"> <mat-icon>open_in_new</mat-icon> Ön İzleme </button> -->
        <button mat-button matRipple class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12" (click)="imageSource()"> Ön İzleme </button>
        <button mat-button matRipple class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12" (click)="close()"> Kapat </button>
    </div>
```

And for the texts, you should wrap them. Like I mentioned.